# Routelink navigation not working in angular 6 when paremeter removes

Tags: angular6

I have my current url with http://localhost:58616/Alerts?alertdate=2019-01-30

I have  [routerLink]="/Alerts"

after click on rourerlink my url go to ->  http://localhost:58616/Alerts
then router is not navigating the page.

this is caused in angular 6

Thanks for viewing my query.

Comment: Please add your route provider code here

Comment: I have only in my *.ts file
@Component({
    selector: 'alert',
    templateUrl: '/app/components/Portal/alert.component.html'
})

Answer (score 0):

please check and post errors if logged in developer console of browser.

Comment: There is no log errors available in browser console.

Comment: please provide router provider configuration from app.module.ts.

Comment: providers: [CommonService, Secure, UnSecure, AdminSecure]

Comment: Router configuration?